# Java mail - No such user exception while sending email to Group email ID

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have an group email ID, while i am sending mail to group email id with OUTLOOK it's working fine. When i am trying send it to same group email id from jAVA MAIL then it is throwing an exception no such user. Where as i am using same SMTP host.

**Exception:**

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
        com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 TestGropuEMAIL@sample.net... No such user

        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1873)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1120)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
        at com.ey.mail.SendEmail.sendMail(SendEmail.java:77)
        at com.ey.main.RunAutoMail.main(RunAutoMail.java:30)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 TestGropuEMAIL@sample.net... No such user

        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1724)
        ... 5 more
```

**Code:**

```
  Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
  message.setHeader("X-Priority", "1");
  message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
  InternetAddress.parse("TestGropuEMAIL@sample.net"));
  BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
  messageBodyPart.setContent(content,"text/html");
  Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
  messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
  String filename = "Test.XLSB";
  DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
  messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
  messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
  message.setContent(multipart);
  Transport.send(message);
```

Can any one help on this?

Comment: If you're using Outlook, you're probably also using Exchange, and Outlook is probably using the Microsoft-proprietary protocol to talk to Exchange.  There may be something about using that protocol that allows it to work but causes it to fail with SMTP.  Perhaps Outlook is expanding the group list on the client side and sending to the members of the group?  If you send to the group, and read the mail using something other than Outlook, what appears in the To header of the message?

Answer (score 0):

It means the mail address is invalid, either the `sender address` or the `receiver address`.I have worked with this project before, post my code here for reference:

```
public boolean sendMail(Properties pro) {
    String host = pro.getProperty("host");
    String userName = pro.getProperty("userName");
    String passWord = pro.getProperty("passWord");
    String subject = pro.getProperty("subject");
    String fileName = pro.getProperty("fileName");
    String receivers = pro.getProperty("receivers");
    String mailContent = pro.getProperty("mailContent");

    System.out.println(mailContent);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    MyAuthenticator myauth = new MyAuthenticator(userName, passWord);
    // Get session
    try {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, myauth);
        // Define message
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        List list = new ArrayList();
        String[] toList = receivers.split(",");// mutilple mail receivers
        for (int i = 0; i < toList.length; i++) {
            list.add(new InternetAddress(toList[i]));
        }
        InternetAddress[] toAddress = (InternetAddress[]) list.toArray(
                new InternetAddress[list.size()]);
        InternetAddress fromAddress = new InternetAddress(userName, "",
                "UTF-8");
        message.setFrom(fromAddress);
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
        message.setSubject(subject);

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // mail content
        BodyPart contentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        contentBodyPart.setContent(mailContent, "text/plain;charset=utf-8");
        multipart.addBodyPart(contentBodyPart);

        // mail attachment
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        FileDataSource source = new FileDataSource(
                pro.getProperty("path") + fileName);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(fileName));
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);
        message.saveChanges();

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, userName, passWord);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Mail Send exception:", e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , My issue is about group email and i am already having code which sends mails successfully.